# Computing the probability that two minima are equal

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X, Y, Z$ be exponential r.v.s with parameters $\lambda$, $\mu$, and $\gamma$.

How can I compute $P(\min(X, Y) = \min(Y, Z))$? I tried to think of case work, but it got really messy. I am wondering if there is a good way. Thank you

Also I found $\min(X, Y) \sim \exp(\lambda + \mu)$ and $\min(Y, Z) \sim \exp(\mu + \gamma)$

Comment: Are you assuming independence? Because otherwise you need their joint probability.

Comment: X, Y, Z are independent

Comment: *Equal*?  Zero. Equality has a positive probability density, but it does not have a positive probability.  (Compare with $P(\min(X,Y) = c)$ for any constant $c$.)

Comment: my book says kurt's answer is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X\neq Z$, $Y\neq X$, etc. with probability 1, to have
$$\min(X,Y)=\min(Y,Z)$$
we need $Y\le X$ and $Y\le Z$. The probability that $Y$ is the smallest is equal to
$$\frac{\mu}{\mu+\lambda+\gamma},$$
which is our answer (this is is a commonly used fact for exponentials).

You can also derive the probability that $Y$ is the smallest by
$$P(X\ge Y, Z\ge Y) = \mathbb{E}_Y[P(X\ge Y, Z\ge Y|Y)] = \mathbb{E}_Y[P(X\ge Y|Y)P(Z\ge Y|Y)] = \mathbb{E}[e^{-(\lambda+\gamma)Y}]$$
The last expectation is just the moment generating function of $Y$ evaluated at $-(\lambda+\gamma)$.

Comment: Thank you. do you happen to know how I can find $\text{Cov}(\min(X, Y), \min(Y, Z))$? i skipped that part because i can't get it

Comment: Well you need $\mathbb{E}[\min(X,Y)]$, and $\min(X,Y) \sim\text{Exp}[\lambda + \mu]$, so that expectation is just $1/(\lambda+\mu)$. Similarly for $\mathbb{E}[\min(Z,Y)]$. To get $\mathbb{E}[\min(X,Y)\min(Y,Z)]$, I think the most straightforward way is to break up that expectation into cases with indicators. In other words  $\mathbb{E}[\min(X,Y)\min(Y,Z)] =  \mathbb{E}[\min(X,Y)\min(Y,Z)\mathbf{1}(Y\le X,Y\le Z)] +  \mathbb{E}[\min(X,Y)\min(Y,Z))\mathbf{1}(Y\ge X,Y\le Z)] + \ldots$.

Comment: If you want to be a little fancier, you can use the law of total covariance and condition on $Y$.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_covariance

Comment: How can I do that? I am still trying to use your hint, but I cannot get it. I will open a new question

Comment: It is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344364/finding-the-covariance-of-two-minimum-random-variables Thank you!