# Finding the expected value of the product of two minimums of r.v.s

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is the early part to a problem that I skipped because I cannot get it. I did all the other parts so I will share them. Let $X, Y, Z$ be exponential r.v. with parameters $\lambda$. $\mu$ and $\gamma$.

Compute $\text{Cov}(\min(X, Y), \min(Y, Z))$.

Some things I know are $\min(X, Y) \sim \exp(\lambda + \mu)$ and $\min(Y, Z) \sim \exp(\mu + \gamma)$

I just need help doing $E(min(X, Y) * min(Y, Z))$. I am pretty sure that I will need to do casework because that's how a lot of these book problems are. But I am not so sure how to do these cases. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that if $A,B$ are independent exponential variables with parameters $\lambda_A$,$\lambda_B$ then $P(A<B) = \dfrac{\lambda_A}{\lambda_A + \lambda_B}$. Also recall $\mathbb{E}[A^2] = \dfrac{1}{\lambda_A^2}$.

It is easy to find $\mathbb{E}[\min(X,Y)]\cdot \mathbb{E}[\min(Y,Z)] = \dfrac{1}{(\lambda + \mu)(\mu + \gamma)}$.

By the law of total probability,

$\mathbb{E}[\min(X,Y)\min(Y,Z)]$ = $\mathbb{P}(X<Y)\mathbb{P}(Y<Z) \mathbb{E}[XY] 
+ \mathbb{P}(Y<X)\mathbb{P}(Y<Z) \mathbb{E}[Y^2] 
+ \mathbb{P}(Y<X)\mathbb{P}(Z<Y) \mathbb{E}[YZ]
+\mathbb{P}(X<Y)\mathbb{P}(Z<Y) \mathbb{E}[XZ]   = \dfrac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}\dfrac{\mu}{\mu+ \gamma}\dfrac{1}{\lambda\mu} + \dfrac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu}\dfrac{\mu}{\mu+ \gamma}\dfrac{1}{\mu^2} + \dfrac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu}\dfrac{\gamma}{\mu+ \gamma}\dfrac{1}{\mu\gamma} + \dfrac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}\dfrac{\gamma}{\mu+ \gamma}\dfrac{1}{\lambda\gamma}=\dfrac{4}{(\lambda + \mu)(\mu + \gamma)}$.

So $Cov\left(min(X,Y),min(Y,Z)\right) = \dfrac{3}{(\lambda + \mu)(\mu + \gamma)}$

Comment: Here's the sketch of an argument why I believe that this answer is not correct. If $\lambda,\gamma\to 0$, then $\min(X,Y)$ and $\min(Y,Z)$ are both equal to $Y$ with arbitrarily high probability. Therefore $\text{Cov}(\min(X,Y), \min(Y,Z))\approx \text{Cov}(Y,Y) = \text{Var}(Y) = 1/\mu^2$, which is very different from what you have. I don't think the law of total probability was applied correctly.

Comment: Where do you think the flaw is?

Comment: I think it's wrong too. Shouldn't $\mathbb{E}[A^2] = \frac{2}{\lambda^{2}_{A}}$? Not $\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}_{A}}$

Comment: @SamuelBodansky when you use the law of total expectation, the expectations need to be conditional expectations. I think the approach is reasonable, we just need to write out the events we are conditioning on.